# Using AWS ECS with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I would like to lunch a Task on ECS cluster and wait for the task termination.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecs')
response = client.run_task(
    cluster='default',
    taskDefinition='RGB',
    overrides={
         'containerOverrides': [
             {
                 'name': 'RGB',
                 'command': [
                     'python', 
                     '-u', 
                     'rgb.py'
                 ]
             }
         ]
     }                   
    )

arn = response["tasks"][0]['taskArn']
waiter = client.get_waiter('tasks_running')
waiter.wait(cluster='default', tasks=[arn])
```

Is it the correct way?

> I am getting: botocore.exceptions.WaiterError: Waiter TasksRunning
>   failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state

Answer (score 15):

Just change:

```
waiter = client.get_waiter('tasks_running')
```

for

```
waiter = client.get_waiter('tasks_stopped')
```